# If $\|A^2\|=\|A\|^2$, then $A$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a linear map 2 dimensional complex vector space, if $$\|A^2\|=\|A\|^2,$$ how to prove $A$ is normal? Is that true for any dimension?

---

In two dimension, we just to need to eliminate the case that $A=\pmatrix{\lambda & 1\\ 0&\lambda}$

Comment: Why do we need to eliminate to this case?